# discord.py (error code: 50027): Invalid Webhook Token

Tags: discord.py, token

I have a big problem.

I code discord bots with python using discord_slash. But since today, evey slash command that I make, it sends **one message** and then it sends an error saying:

```
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 50027): Invalid Webhook Token
```

So commands that sends 2 messages only sends one.

It does this to all my bots with slash commands.

This is an example of command that I make (just so you see it's a regular command):

```
@slash.slash(name = "Ping", description = "Check the bots time response")
async def ping(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "Pong.", description = f"**:chicken: `{int(bot.latency * 1000)}` ms**")
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

I tried reinstalling discord.py and it cannot be a token problem since it does the error on all my bots.

(I specify the fact that I checked many forums)

A help would be great thank you

Comment: I'm seeing this with my bots too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not you, it's Discord...

Per their Discord Server (https://discord.gg/discord-developers):

> Discord User — Today at 6:12 AM
>
> Hi everyone. There is currently an issue being investigated with
> interaction edits, deletes, and followups. This issue results in
> receiving 50027: Invalid Webhook Token errors when trying to edit,
> delete, follow up, or take some other actions on interaction webhooks.

> Discord User — Today at 8:37 AM
>
> Webhook token problem has been identified and we are working on
> rolling out a fix. We will update this message when it is
> resolved.][1](https://discord.com/channels/613425648685547541/697138785317814292/1000027443270271066)

> Discord User 2 — Today at 9:43 AM
>
> The webhook token problem should be fixed.
>
> As a reminder, we saw a Snowflake length increase to 19 characters
> today! Snowflakes are 64 bit integers, so the max base 10 length is 20
> digits now.

Comment: ok thanks for the answer ! Now, let's just wait 

Comment: could you just send the invite to the server discord where this message was sent please ? Because I cant view the message since i'm not in the server